# Pyspark Distinct records form the string column by considering Null values in groupby

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-schema

I have a **dataframe** like the following:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(22,'fl1.variant,fl2.variant,fl3.control','xxx','yyy','zzz'),(22,'fl1.variant, fl2.neither,fl3.control','xxx','yyy','NULL'),
    (22,'fl1.variant, fl2.neither,fl4.control','xxx','yyy','NULL').(22,'fl4.variant,fl2.variant,fl4.variant','xxx1','yyy1','zzz1'),(22,'fl3.control,fl3.control,fl3.variant','xxx1','yyy1','zzz1'),
    (22,'NULL','xxx1','yyy1','zzz1')])

df = rdd.toDF(['Date','Type','Data1','Data2','Data3'])
```

**Sample data :**

| Date | Type | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | fl1.variant,fl2.variant,fl3.control | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| 22 | fl1.variant,fl2.neither,fl3.control | xxx | yyy | null |
| 22 | fl1.variant,fl2.neither,fl4.control | xxx | yyy | null |
| 22 | fl4.variant,fl2.variant,fl4.variant | xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 |
| 22 | fl3.control,fl3.control,fl3.variant | xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 |
| 22 |  | xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 |

I need to identify the distinct values of **Type** column data based on **Data1**, **Data2** and **Data3** columns. **Type** column's datatype is string separated by **,**.

Based on **Data1**, **Data2**, **Data3**, I need to combine all the data and identify the unique values of **Type** column.

**expected output :**

| data1 | data2 | data3 | type_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | yyy | zzz | [fl1.variant, fl2.variant,fl2.neither, fl3.control,fl4.control] |
| xxx1 | yyy1 | zzz1 | [fl4.variant, fl2.variant, fl3.control, fl3.variant] |

I tried like below but could not get the expected distinct values

```
data_df. \
        withColumn('type_split', func.split('type', ',')). \
        groupBy('data1','data2','data3'). \
     agg(func.array_distinct(func.flatten(func.collect_list('type_split'))).alias('type_list')). \
        show(truncate=False)
```

```
|data1|data2|data3|type_list|
|:----|:----|:----|:------------|
|xxx|yyy|zzz|[fl1.variant, fl2.variant,fl3.control]|
|xxx|yyy|NULL|[fl1.variant,  fl2.neither,fl3.control, fl4.control]|
|xxx1|yyy1|zzz1|[fl4.variant, fl2.variant,fl3.control,fl3.variant, ]|
```

In the above data second record is also get flatten irrespective of **NULL** value.

In the third record of **Type_list** there is a **empty** value in the array.

Comment: Your requirement leads to a conflict. How will you map the NULL value for `data3` if say all `data1`="xxx" and `data2`="yyy"? Now you have 3 `data3` values: "zzz", NULL and "zzz1". Where will you map the NULL?

Comment: You need some rule to fill the missing data.

Comment: can we consider date column and flatten the records ?

Comment: let us say in group by have data3 values: "zzz", NULL . so we can consider zzz and flatten records

Comment: Still the same issue - you have these values for same date: "zzz", NULL, "zzz1". There is no order here - it can also be NULL, "zzz1", "zzz".